# How to disable private browsing for firefox and google on Linux

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, gnome-terminal

Already tried /usr/lib/firefox/distribution.  Would not allow. Tried mkdir distribution because it said I already had firefox.  It then made a distribution folder. Entered  sudo touch policies.json and that was okay but then when entering sudo nano policies.json and pasted in a stream like:   {"policies":{DisablePrivateBrowsing": true}} it would not let me save or exit after that for it was in read only I believe.

Answer (score 0):

To disable incognito on chrome/chromium you need to edit the policies. Doing this will prevent you from opening an incognito window via Ctrl+Shift+n, and will also grey out the incognito window option in the options tab in the corner.

If you're using chrome, create the folder /etc/opt/chrome/policies/managed. Or if you're using chromium, create the folder /etc/chromium/policies/managed.

Then create a file in that directory named test_policy.json. It can have any name you want, but it needs the extension to be .json.

Open it in your favorite editor and put:

{
"IncognitoModeAvailability": 1
}
That should do it!